safe concurrent insert into snowflake without causing duplicates
i know that in general concurrent execution of the below can cause duplicates, as both queries hit the same point in time for the Existence check, and decide to insert.
INSERT INTO stg.my_table  -- column list here
SELECT src.*
FROM stg.my_view AS src
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM  stg.my_table AS tgt
                  WHERE tgt.ID = src.ID);

In Sql Server PK violation, locking, or optimistic concurrency under RCSI would prevent actual duplicates from landing by ID.
Question: How do i do this safely in Snowflake?
Concurrent inserts of the same ID are very rare, so i would prefer a solution that is cheap for the non-exceptional path. Preferably it would allow multiple concurrent inserts into the one table.
For now, i'm having to run certain groups of inserts into the same table serially.

Your code is only doing a SELECT, not an INSERT. Assuming you are trying to insert data, please update your question with your actual code

It seems your workload requires a lot of atomic row-level inserts. In that case you can consider hybrid tables which enforce PK/UQ constraints.

@NickW - it was there in the raw code, but the formatting ate the first row of my code.. (fixed now)

@LukaszSzozda in general the inserts could be done without the 'if not exists' clause, at the moment that is there to guard against accidental double processing. It works well serially. But i would like to parallelise the inserts. I don't mind paying a high cost of of error handling on (very) rare failure.
I may be able to have a hybrid table keep track of something at a higher level to emulate a range lock rather than having to do something per row ...
Hybrid tables are still a partially available preview feature - thankfully my primary aws zone is on the list ...

Have you considered just inserting everything into a base table concurrently and then slapping a view or materialized view over it that dedupes for you?  I guarantee that this will be faster on the insert side by quite a lot and the extra compute on an MV would likely be low, if dupes are rare.

@MikeWalton's proposal is what I've seen in Snowflake. It's OLAP model doesn't want to serialise activity. As you point out you can get into hand building OLTP locking structures (like the range lock you mention). That implementation encounters rare (but harmful) duplicates and uses a downstream PARTITION and QUALIFY for ROW_NUMBER()=1 to pick a unique (and stable) row where (rare) duplicates exist.
It has the advantage of retaining all the versions so the result can be changed if the disambiguation criteria are refined.
